# Allow users to vote up, or down, or nothing

Tags: django, django-models, django-users

I have made an app to create article. This is the model:

```
class Article(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    body = models.TextField()
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag)
    article_image = models.ImageField(upload_to=get_upload_file_name, blank=True)
```

Here I want to setup a voting system for each app. There I would like give the users the feature to vote up, or vote down, or do nothing. Boolean field would have been great, but since an article can have 3 choices of votes  (vote up / vote down / or default = no vote ), how should I go about doing this? Your help and guidance will be very much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Interger with constant values. Or an integer mapped enum type.